# How to convert an existing Azure Web Role to a new-style Azure Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to convert an existing Azure Web Role (which is ASP.NET MVC) to a new [Azure Web Site](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/)?  Other than just creating a new project and copying the code over to the new project so that it looks like the old application, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Windows Azure Web-Sites are shared sites with others on the same machien and you don't have capability to Remote into. You sure can manage the sites direly from Git or Powershell. Also new Azure web-site design does not use any of the Web Role Model so you just need to take your ASP.NET website application and export as your new ASP.NET Web site.

Comment: The answer to my question is:  "No, there is no way to convert an existing web role to a web site."  Your answer almost comes out and says that, but has a bunch of other unrelated commentary (about GIT and the fact that they are shared, and the fact that you can't remote into them) that confuses the answer.  If you want to edit your answer to be more clear, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to create a new project. Technically a Windows Azure Web Role Project is simply an ASP.NET site (or WCF application) which has an additional project type which is a Cloud Service Project.

Technically if you remove the cloud service project you have a site that will work in Windows Azure Web Sites with the following caveats:

1. Start-Up Tasks are part of the Cloud Service model and will not be available
2. WebRole.cs aka RoleEntryPoint will not execute
3. If you had a Worker role in your project, there is no equivalent in Windows Azure Web Sites.

The majority of the other features will work, with a few exception (but keep in mind it's currently in preview).